# Sharing through the People app

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-store-apps

On Windows 8, people app declares in its `AppxManifest.xml` that it accepts data in all three formats: text, html and uri.  However, it seems to use only the URI.

I would expect that I should be able to post a simple message of the kind `“Check this out <uri>”` on both Facebook and Twitter (using People app) by using both `SetText(“Check this out”)` and `SetURI(uri)` in my app.  The Rowi app seems to accept the data in this way but People app seems to ignore the text when my app sends the data in this format.

Is it possible to construct a message with both text and uri to post through People app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From MSDN:
“If your app can support multiple formats, and all those formats are present in the content being shared, we recommend that you process only the format that is the most relevant to your app. For example, if your app shares links, and it receives shared content that has both a link and some text, your app should process only the link.”

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh771179.aspx

Basically, the data in all formats is expected to be equivalent, with richer formats containing more details, and the others being fallback options in case a target app doesn’t support the richer option (for example, you might share HTML that is nicely formatted, but include a text version with just the plain text content).

In Rowi's case, they inspect the data formats they accept (text, html, uri) and concatenate all of them in to the presented message.  Whereas People app seems to prioritize and present only one based on that prioritization.